# All checks pass - Mail still goes into spam

Tags: email, spam

I got a self-hosted mail server using nethserver.

No matter what I do, the mail I send still goes into the unwanted mail on Gmail and Office365.

It's exclusively personal mail.

My IP nor my Domain are on any blacklist.

check-auth@verifier.port25.com results:
    SPF check:          pass "iprev" check:      pass DKIM check:         pass SpamAssassin check: ham

```
HELO hostname:  i.domain.tld Source IP:      xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx mail-from:      info@domain.tld

---------------------------------------------------------- SPF check details:
---------------------------------------------------------- Result:         pass ID(s) verified: smtp.mailfrom=info@domain.tld

DNS record(s):
    domain.tld. 60 IN TXT "v=spf1 ptr ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32 a:i.domain.tld a:mail.domain.tld -all"
    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.in-addr.arpa. 60 IN PTR domain.tld.
    domain.tld. 60 IN A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx


---------------------------------------------------------- "iprev" check details:
---------------------------------------------------------- Result:         pass (matches domain.tld) ID(s) verified: policy.iprev=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

DNS record(s):
    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.in-addr.arpa. 60 IN PTR domain.tld.
    domain.tld. 60 IN A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx


---------------------------------------------------------- DKIM check details:
---------------------------------------------------------- Result:         pass (matches From: info@domain.tld) ID(s) verified: header.d=domain.tld

Canonicalized Headers:
    to:check-auth@verifier.port25.com'0D''0A'
    from:Raylin'20'<info@domain.tld>'0D''0A'
    subject:Werkt'20'dit?'0D''0A'
    date:Fri,'20'12'20'Apr'20'2019'20'12:18:45'20'+0200'0D''0A'
    dkim-signature:v=1;'20'a=rsa-sha256;'20'c=relaxed/relaxed;'20'd=domain.tld;'20's=default;'20't=1555064325;'20'bh=1RpqxxjguSMkMVzn75FFHRz1u2KEM0ZVTOYlX8HAKE8=;'20'h=To:From:Subject:Date:From;'20'b=
---------------------------------------------------------- SpamAssassin check details:
---------------------------------------------------------- SpamAssassin v3.4.0 (2014-02-07)

Result:         ham (-2.0 points, 5.0 required)

 pts rule name              description
---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
-1.9 BAYES_00               BODY: Bayes spam probability is 0 to 1%
                            [score: 0.0000]
 0.0 URIBL_BLOCKED          ADMINISTRATOR NOTICE: The query to URIBL was blocked.
                            See
                            http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/DnsBlocklists#dnsbl-block
                             for more information.
                            [URIs: domain.tld]
-0.0 SPF_PASS               SPF: sender matches SPF record
 0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
-0.1 DKIM_VALID_AU          Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from author's
                            domain
-0.1 DKIM_VALID             Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
 0.1 DKIM_SIGNED            Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily valid
```

does anybody have an idea what the cause of this is?

Comment: It's a duplicate of neither...